# How to filter firebase recycler view?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have an android app linked with my firestore database. I am fetching data from the firestore and displaying the results in a recycler view with the help of firebaseRecyclerView. My app is working perfectly and I'm able to display all the results in my recycler view.

Now I want to add the feature of filtering the already fetched data using a spinner. i.e the user first sees all the results, then uses the spinner to display only the relevant data.
I'm able to manage the case when there are no results from the firestore/recycler view that is empty.

To filter, I think I may have to use the onItemSelected function of the spinner, however, I don't know how I should proceed.
To filter I would be basically comparing two strings.
One from the text selected from the spinner , and one from each Textview of the row of recyclerview.

Please let me know how I should proceed.

Here is my onCreate method:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_query);

      
filter_price_text = findViewById(R.id.filter_price_text);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_tProfile);
        emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);


        query = db
                .collection("tUsers")
                .whereEqualTo(testArray[0], true)
                .whereEqualTo(testArray[1], true)
                .whereEqualTo("pincode", customerPincode)
                .whereEqualTo("sector", customerSector); //query is working . ignore what I'm querying for. I have removed unimportant data from onCreate


        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<TProfileModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<TProfileModel>().setQuery(query, TProfileModel.class).build();
        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<TProfileModel, profileViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public profileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.t_profile_row, parent, false);

                return new profileViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull profileViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final TProfileModel model) { //final added manually to test should remove
                holder.t_name.setText(model.getName());
                String tsector = "Sector : " + model.getSector();
                holder.t_sector.setText(tsector);
                String tpin = "Pincode : " + model.getPincode();
                holder.t_pincode.setText(tpin);
                String trating = "Rating : " + model.getRating();
                holder.t_rating.setText(trating);
                String tprice = "Avg. Price : " + model.getAvgPriceRange();
                holder.t_price.setText(tprice);
                ta_price = model.getAvgPriceRange();//will be used for comparing with spinner data

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainQueryActivity.this, ViewTActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", model.getName());
                        intent.putExtra("sector", model.getSector());
                        intent.putExtra("pincode", model.getPincode());
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                emptyView.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                priceFilter.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                filter_price_text.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                // Called when there is an error getting a query snapshot. You may want to update
                // your UI to display an error message to the user.
                // ...
            }


        };

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        priceFilter = findViewById(R.id.priceFilter_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.t_price_spin, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        priceFilter.setAdapter(adapter1);

        final String spinner_price = priceFilter.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

        priceFilter.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //compare ta_price with spinner_price

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: What is the content of this?  R.array.t_price_spin

Comment: strings, consider them as "item 1","item 2","item 3". When user clicks on item 1,I store "item 1" in a seperate string namely spinner_price